# What is best recommended way to call an external web service from Web Application in java?

Tags: eclipse, web-services, web-applications, ejb

I am creating a web application in eclipse (via dynamic web project wizard). the Main job of this web app is to call an External web Service's Methods. to accomplish this task should i make an EJB which will call this web service or  should i go with creating a Web Service Client. what are the best practices and recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple - just create a web service client.  Unless you have reasons for using EJBs (perhaps distributed transactions) you are over-engineering.  You can always add this later if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use [Java Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) for this. Here goes a clean [tutorial](http://137.254.16.27/enterprisetechtips/entry/consuming_restful_web_services_with)